# Cannot add a textField to a scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I am VERY new to Flutter (like a week). I am attempting to add a search field above a list view. Sounds simple. However I get an error that is not making sense to me (even after tons of googling and reading the docs). I understand the error, just not why I'm getting it.

```
return Scaffold(
        body :
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          child:
          TextField(
            controller: searchController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: "search text",
                border: OutlineInputBorder()
            ), //decoration
          ), //textfield
        ), // padding
        ListView.builder(
          itemCount : contactsModel.entityList.length,
          itemBuilder : (BuildContext inBuildContext, int inIndex) {
            Contact contact = contactsModel.entityList[inIndex];
            return Column(
              children : [
                Slidable(
                  delegate : SlidableDrawerDelegate(),
                  actionExtentRatio : .25,
                  child : ListTile(
                    title : Text("${contact.password}"),
                    subtitle : contact.pwordHint == null ? null : Text("${contact.pwordHint} - ${contact.notes}"),
                    // Edit existing contact.
                    onTap : () async {
                      contactsModel.entityBeingEdited = await ContactsDBWorker.db.get(contact.id);
                      contactsModel.setStackIndex(1);
                    }
                  ),
                  secondaryActions : [
                    IconSlideAction(
                      caption : "Delete",
                      color : Colors.red,
                      icon : Icons.delete,
                      onTap : () => _deleteContact(inContext, contact)
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                Divider()
              ]
            ); /* End Column. */
          } /* End itemBuilder. */
        ), /* End ListView.builder. */
          floatingActionButton : FloatingActionButton(
            child : Icon(Icons.add, color : Colors.white),
            onPressed : () async {
              contactsModel.entityBeingEdited = Contact();
              contactsModel.setStackIndex(1);
            }
          ),
      ); /* End Scaffold. */
```

The errors I get are:

```
error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named at SCAFFOLD LINE
error: Positional arguments must occur before named arguments. (positional_after_named_argument at LISTVIEW.BUILDER LINE
```

If I delete the PADDING() section after "BODY :" no errors.

I'm not sure why Listview is different than Padding. I think I am missing one or more flutter fundamental concepts that would make the answer obvious. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using

```
Scaffold(
  body: Widget1(),
        Widget2(),
  ...
)
```

Here `Widget1` is your `Padding` and `Widget2` is `ListView.builder`

This isn't the correct way. You can wrap your `Widget1` and `Widget2` in either `Stack` or `Column`, whichever suits your need, like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Widget1(),
      Widget2(),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: That makes a huge amount of sense now that it's pointed out to me. Practice will make better. Thanks.

Comment: Do I have to specify flexible somewhere because I am getting a "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height." error at run time? Or is there another way to specify the Column height? If I do, where?

Comment: Wrap your `ListView` inside `Expanded`.

Comment: I wrapped the ListView.builder with: "Expanded(" and ")," no difference.

Comment: Can you post another question with code, I will answer it real quick.

Comment: Just did. Flutter column will no render